# How to cache "poetry install" for Gitlab CI?

Tags: python, gitlab, continuous-integration, python-poetry

Is there a way to cache `poetry install` command in Gitlab CI (`.gitlab-ci.yml`)?

For example, in `node` `yarn` there is a way to cache `yarn install` (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install-ci/ `Gitlab` section) this makes stages a lot faster.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[GitLab can only cache things in the working directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cache) and Poetry [stores packages elsewhere by default](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvspath):

> Directory where virtual environments will be created. Defaults to `{cache-dir}/virtualenvs` (`{cache-dir}\virtualenvs` on Windows).

On my machine, `cache-dir` is `/home/chris/.cache/pypoetry`.

You can use [the `virtualenvs.in-project` option](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project) to change this behaviour:

> If set to true, the virtualenv wil be created and expected in a folder named `.venv` within the root directory of the project.

So, something like this should work in your `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
before_script:
  - poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true

cache:
  paths:
    - .venv
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it seems that the bottle neck in our case are the slow shared CI machines of Gitlab

Comment: @Angel, another factor is that caches aren't shared between runners by default. You can tag your runners and make sure to use the same one for the same job, or you can [configure distributed caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching).

Answer (score 1):

You can set [the Poetry virtualenv cache directory](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvspath) to something within the GitLab project space, e.g.:

```
variables:
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_PATH: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/venv
```

and then cache it like normal:

```
cache:
    paths:
        - venv
```