# Missing pytest-asyncio package in gitlab-ci cache

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, aiohttp

I'm implementing my version of [aiohttp chat sample](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-demos/tree/master/demos/chat), using:

- Python 3.10
- poetry as dep manager
- pytest for tests

I've installed those dev deps:

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^7.1.2"
pytest-aiohttp = "^1.0.4"
```

If I run:

```
$ ls .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ | grep -i 'pytest_asyncio'

pytest_asyncio
pytest_asyncio-0.19.0.dist-info
```

But in [GitlabCI runs](https://gitlab.com/danieletentoni/plinplin/-/jobs/2726400576) I see those errors:

```
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
tests/test_chat.py::test_msg_sending
  /builds/danieletentoni/[MASKED]/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:181: PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning: async def functions are not natively supported and have been skipped.
  You need to install a suitable plugin for your async framework, for example:
    - anyio
    - pytest-asyncio
    - pytest-tornasync
    - pytest-trio
    - pytest-twisted
    warnings.warn(PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning(msg.format(nodeid)))
tests/test_chat.py::test_msg_sending
  /builds/danieletentoni/[MASKED]/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:136: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'client' was never awaited
    item.funcargs = None  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  Enable tracemalloc to get traceback where the object was allocated.
  See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html#resource-warnings for more info.
-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
======================== 1 skipped, 2 warnings in 0.10s ========================
```

Making me skipping the single test I have.
In my local env I can execute tests without skipping.

Could you help me?

Comment: How do you run your tests locally? With `poetry shell`? Are you installing all dependencies with `poetry install` before running the tests on GitlabCI?

Comment: In both local and ci I run `poetry install` and then `poetry run python3 -m pytest tests/`. What change in ci is that I first run `poetry install`, cache `.venv` folder and then restore it. You can check my ci file [here](https://gitlab.com/danieletentoni/plinplin/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml#L20). I'm using a simple script to check if my cache is present or not, and it does.

Comment: Is `pytest_asyncio` listed as a dependency on your `pyproject.toml`? It seems to me this is what is missing.

Comment: @Marco.S I've listed `pytest-aiohttp = "^1.0.4"`, that have a dependancy pytest-asyncio, since running `poetry install` it install `• Installing pytest-asyncio (0.19.0)`

Comment: I think the issue is related to storing the Poetry's cache in GitLab. Please refer to [this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71240277/5489111).